# How to find a rental lawyer in Spain

Tags: legal, spain, rental

I'm a foreigner living in Badajoz Spain. I signed a rental contract for 1 year. I need advice on how to get out of the contract early.

As I do not have any close friends or relatives in Spain that I can rely on, how do I find a rental lawyer?

1. Are they any associations that can help with rental problems?
2. Any official list of lawyers available in a city?

---

What I've tried?

1. I googled for "espana badajoz abogados"
2. I went to google maps and searched for abogados in Badajoz.

Maybe there is a better strategy than internet searches?

Comment: What sources have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried just asking whoever the other party is? If they have a chance to rent it out again (maybe even to a higher price than you paid), they might be indifferent or even happy to cut the contract short. Legal advice is always a good idea, but don't go nuclear unless you know for a fact that you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to an official list would be the "lawyer list" *(censo de letrados)* on the [Badajoz bar association](https://www.icaba.es) page, albeit it looks rather limited. There's also a "citizen's assistance" (*atención al ciudadano*) phone listed on top of the page.